# htaccess and php to dissect REQUEST_URI or QUERY_STRING

Tags: php, .htaccess

how can i use htaccess to catch a friendly url like

`/error/access/notallowed`

and break it down to

`error.php?$1=$2`

but the real question is what if i have another url

`/something/name/joe/address/123_Maples_Lane/city/somewhere`

and do the same thing dynamically if all the odd segments are key value pairs to the even segments.

would I need PHP to do the splits in segments or can htaccess create the query on the fly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

apache can't create a rewrite with an arbitrary number of parameters since it has to work off of a PCRE expression.  You would have to use PHP to do this.  However, apache, is still involved:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT]
```

This will route all nonexistent requests to `index.php/` and the request will be the path.  Then, you can break down the path on `index.php`.

Comment: ah thats what i was thinking. So from your example in the index.php I would split the $_GET? or how would that request look like? would I split the QUERY_STRING?

Comment: you would split `_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]`.  If `_SERVER[PATH_INFO]` is available, that's even better, but it is not always available.